# Count rows based on row value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am calling a stored procedure that returns a table with two columns, an ident (integer) and a score (float4).  The integer column will be unique values.  I now want to know how many rows in the table have a larger/smaller score than the ident with a given value.  I'm struggling to figure out how to do that in SQL.  If it were something like PHP I'd sort the returned data by score, find the index of the row that has the ident I am looking for, and then subtract that from the total # of rows, for example.  In PostgreSQL 9.1.15, I'm not sure how to do that.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM my_stored_proc()
WHERE score > *Score of person with given ident*
ORDER BY score;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about ident = 2, you can do:

```
select sum(case when t.score < t2.score then 1 else 0 end) as LessThan,
       sum(case when t.score > t2.score then 1 else 0 end) as GreaterThan
from table t cross join
     (select t.* from table where ident = 2) t2;
```

If you only want to reference the table once (as you would if accessing it were expensive), you could do the above with a CTE or you could do:

```
select sum(case when score < score2 then 1 else 0 end) as LessThan,
       sum(case when score > score2 then 1 else 0 end) as GreaterThan
from (select t.*,
             max(case when ident = 2 then score end) over () as score2
      from table t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT worse, better
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ident,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY score ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) worse,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY score ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) better,
  FROM my_stored_proc()
) t
WHERE ident = 2; -- replace with the "ident" you care about
```

This will simply count the number of rows in the result set that are above or below the current row if ordered by score.

Anyway, [Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) solution might be slightly better, as it takes into account the possibility of an `ident` being returned more than once from your `my_stored_proc()`, and taking each `ident`'s maximum score.

Comment: That gives me the values for everyone, as part of the result set.  I want to just get the number above/below based on a specific ident.

Comment: @Gargoyle: I'm not sure if I understand. Can you please post an example expected output? I feel that this query is the correct answer to your current wording...

Comment: So let's say the table returns idents 1, 2, 3, and 4, with scores of 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and 4.0.  I now want to know how many people are better/worse than just ident 2, so there's 1 score smaller and two scores larger.  So your code is giving the results for each person, but I just want the values 1 and 2 returned as I only care about person with ident 2.  Does that clarify it any better?

Comment: @Gargoyle: Aha, I see. Yes the misunderstanding was on my side, then. But it would just be a simple, additional filter on my query.

Comment: (Note that you can edit your question here on Stack Overflow to add additional information)